# Python convert array of strings to array of bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, arraylist

I am trying to convert an array of strings `oldlist = ['00000100', '10100001', '11000001', '11100001']` that are binary values into bytes of their value as hex codes so the resulting list would look like this `newlist = [b'\x04', b'\xa1', b'\xc1', b'\xe1']`. I get the basic concept of looping through the first list and appended to the previous or doing some sort of list comp. But I can't find a function to convert "00000100" to " b'\x04' "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `int(number, 2)` to convert the string to integer:

```
oldlist = ["00000100", "10100001", "11000001", "11100001"]

out = list(map(lambda x: bytes([int(x, 2)]), oldlist))
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[b'\x04', b'\xa1', b'\xc1', b'\xe1']
```

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is to use `string.getBytes();`

Comment: This does not work. If you try it with a simple string, say, `"Hello World!"`, you will get an error message along these lines: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'getBytes'`. It appears that you are thinking of Java; this question is directed for Python.

Comment: oops really sorry about that mistake. Yeah, i thought it in Java. So the same think in Python is bytes()

Answer (score 0):

You first need to convert the binary string to an integer. For this you can use int() method with radix of 2. Then to convert that to bytes, use the bytes() method like this bytes([x]).

```
>>> oldlist = ['00000100', '10100001', '11000001', '11100001']
>>> list(map(lambda x: bytes([int(x, 2)]), oldlist))
[b'\x04', b'\xa1', b'\xc1', b'\xe1']
```